# Correct use of recent

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Consider the following example:

```
Some of these technologies are as recent as three months old.
```

I the above sentence correct, and is it a normal way to convey the meaning in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sentence

> Some of these technologies are as recent as three months old.

is understandable, and for emphasis

> Some of these technologies are **only** as recent as three months old.

but a better way to express it might be

> Some of these technologies are **only** three months old.

Answer (score 0):

Although your sentence is understandable, it is ungrammatical.

The complement of **as recent as** is a *point-in-time* reference:

```
yesterday
two months ago
last year
this morning
1989
etc
```

a predicate  complement:

> The news must be as recent as (is) *possible*.

or a clause complement:

> The model of the car must be as recent as *you can manage*.
>
> The model of the car must be as recent as *we can afford*.

{age} does not work:

> These technologies are as recent as *three months old* 
>   <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

A baby was born recently. The birth was recent. But to say that the baby is "as recent as six months old" is not grammatical.

Comment: what about (is) three months old?

Comment: **three months old** is  a perfectly valid subject complement with "BE (is/are/etc)".  You could say *Some of these technologies are only three months old.*  (as Peter recommended at the bottom of his answer)